# Evaluate dynamic string as an XPath expression?

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

Currently, I'm writing something to do Unit testing for XSLT2 functions, the idea is very simple:

1. Create a `custom-library.xsl`, which contains some custom XSLT2 functions.
2. Create a data XML contains the test cases, as following XML Schema [xslunit.xsd](http://xml.bodz.net/schema/xslunit/xslunit.xsd):

   [schema structure http://xml.bodz.net/schema/xslunit/xslunit.png](http://xml.bodz.net/schema/xslunit/xslunit.png)
3. Run the test cases by transform it, using [xslunit-xslt2.xsl](http://xml.bodz.net/schema/xslunit/xslunit-xslt2.xsl), and get the test result html.

Now, the question is, there is function-call in the test cases, and I have to evaluate it in the XSLT (file [xslunit-xslt2.xsl](http://xml.bodz.net/schema/xslunit/xslunit-xslt2.xsl)). But I can't find a way to evaluate an XPath.

Though, it may be easy to using some kind of Java extensions, but I really don't want to bring in another trouble. I hope everything can just work with-in XSLT2 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pure XSLT 2.0 does not have support do evaluate an XPath expression found in your XML data. Saxon 9 (in its commercial editions) however has an extension function: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/evaluate.xml. And AltovaXML Tools has a similar one: http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlcommunity/index.html?xextaltova_general.htm

Comment: I guess http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html is also worth mentioning. It's implemented, for example, in libxslt, which is still in 1.0 world.

Comment: thanks for the altova link, though I'm just use the editor at all.  If I have determined which tool to use, there is always an extension way. So I'm considering a different approach for unit testing of xslt.

Answer (score 1):

**Update a decade later**: XSLT 3.0 has an instruction `<xsl:evaluate>` which evaluates an XPath expression supplied dynamically as a string.