# How to parse references in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a code like this

```
<Library>
    <Books>
        <Book>
            <ISBN>123</ISBN>
            <Name>Book 1</Name>
            <Author-Ref>/Library/Authors/Author[2]</Author-Ref>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <ISBN>425</ISBN>
            <Name>Book 2</Name>
            <Author-Ref>/Library/Authors/Author[1]</Author-Ref>
        </Book>     
    </Books>
    <Authors>
        <Author>
            <Name>John smith</Name>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
            <BirthDate>08051977</BirthDate>
        </Author>
        <Author>
            <Name>Sandra Johns</Name>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
            <BirthDate>03091981</BirthDate>
        </Author>       
    </Authors>
</Library>
```

And i want to write xslt code, to print Book Name, Auther Name.

How do i parse the reference to the Auther name using the XSLT?

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Library/Books/Book">
    Book Name: <xsl:value-of select="./Name"/>
    Auther Name: ?????
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This is not currently possible in standard XSLT.  However, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4593170/18157) might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluate dynamic string as an XPath expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591452/evaluate-dynamic-string-as-an-xpath-expression)

Comment: @JimGarrison It is possible using XSLT 3.0 using the `xsl:evaluate` function. This is implemented e.g. in Saxon (although a commercial licence is required). Details at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/conformance/xslt30.html

Comment: Is there any possibility of the XML being changed to use a simple ID as the reference?

Comment: Runtime evaluation of XPath expressions is available in XSLT 1.0 via extension functions, e.g., the EXSLT `dyn:evaluate` or Saxon's `saxon:evaluate`. If you have any control over the XML serialization of your data, you can also consider ID/IDREF or similar linkage, which would not require extension functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in 2 phases; First phase is to add the path to the `Author` elements. Second phase to use the added path to produce the desired output.

This could be done in a single XSLT (2.0) by putting the new input with the path added in a variable, but this would cause memory issues with larger documents.

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```
<Library>
    <Books>
        <Book>
            <ISBN>123</ISBN>
            <Name>Book 1</Name>
            <Author-Ref>/Library/Authors/Author[2]</Author-Ref>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <ISBN>425</ISBN>
            <Name>Book 2</Name>
            <Author-Ref>/Library/Authors/Author[1]</Author-Ref>
        </Book>     
    </Books>
    <Authors>
        <Author>
            <Name>John smith</Name>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
            <BirthDate>08051977</BirthDate>
        </Author>
        <Author>
            <Name>Sandra Johns</Name>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
            <BirthDate>03091981</BirthDate>
        </Author>       
    </Authors>
</Library>
```

**First XSLT** (pass1.xsl)

This will add the attribute `path` to the `Author` elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="self::Author">
                <xsl:attribute name="path">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',local-name())"/>
                        <xsl:if test="(preceding-sibling::*|following-sibling::*)[local-name()=local-name(current())]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())])+1,']')"/>                      
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output** (temp.xml)

Notice `@path` has been added.

```
<Library>
   <Books>
      <Book>
         <ISBN>123</ISBN>
         <Name>Book 1</Name>
         <Author-Ref>/Library/Authors/Author[2]</Author-Ref>
      </Book>
      <Book>
         <ISBN>425</ISBN>
         <Name>Book 2</Name>
         <Author-Ref>/Library/Authors/Author[1]</Author-Ref>
      </Book>
   </Books>
   <Authors>
      <Author path="/Library/Authors/Author[1]">
         <Name>John smith</Name>
         <Nationality>American</Nationality>
         <BirthDate>08051977</BirthDate>
      </Author>
      <Author path="/Library/Authors/Author[2]">
         <Name>Sandra Johns</Name>
         <Nationality>American</Nationality>
         <BirthDate>03091981</BirthDate>
      </Author>
   </Authors>
</Library>
```

**Second XSLT** (pass2.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*/Books/Book">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Book Name: ',Name,'&#xA;')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Author Name: ',
        /*/Authors/Author[@path=current()/Author-Ref]/Name,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Final Output**

```
Book Name: Book 1
Author Name: Sandra Johns
Book Name: Book 2
Author Name: John smith
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to mix a bit of unix shell script with the `xmlstarlet` tool. The `xmlstarlet` command that serves input to the `while` loop

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t \
    -m "/Library/Books/Book" \
    -v "concat( Name, '>', Author-Ref )" \
    -n \
xmlfile
```

searches for the `Name` and the `Author-Ref` content and prints both separated with character `>`. It would fail if either of both fields contains that character.

```
Book 1>/Library/Authors/Author[2]
Book 2>/Library/Authors/Author[1]
```

Inside the loop print the name and execute a second `xmlstarlet` command with the `xpath` of `author_ref` to extract the author name.

The complete command:

```
while IFS=">" read -r name author_ref; do
    printf "Book name: %s\n" "$name"
    printf "Author Name: %s\n" "$(xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "${author_ref}/Name" xmlfile)"
done < <(xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "/Library/Books/Book" -v "concat( Name, '>', Author-Ref )" -n xmlfile)
```

That yields:

```
Book name: Book 1
Author Name: Sandra Johns
Book name: Book 2
Author Name: John smith
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
    extension-element-prefixes="dyn"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/Library/Books/Book">
            <xsl:text>Book Name: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./Name"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x000A;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>Auther Name: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate(Author-Ref)/Name"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x000A;</xsl:text>                
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

tested with Xalan and Xsltproc to produce this output with the provided input:

```
Book Name: Book 1
Auther Name: Sandra Johns
Book Name: Book 2
Auther Name: John smith
```

Note that you will need to have the EXSLT modules available to your processor. I am not a Xalan user, but based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377811/using-dynamic-xpath-in-xslt) answer, there is a `xalan:evaluate` as well. If you're using Saxon, you can update with

```
xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="saxon:evaluate(Author-Ref)/Name"/>
```