# Dynamically change the value-of in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I work in xslt 2.0 and I have a line in my code like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//dbquery[@id='INLIJVING']//rows/row[@BudgetaryEnvelop_Year = $RefBef][1]/@BudgetaryEnvelop_Year"/></xsl:variable>
```

This works fine. But I want to write this with a dynamic parameter name instead of `@BudgetaryEnvelop_Year`.

I tried to define a param `$target` and to change the line like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//dbquery[@id='INLIJVING']//rows/row[$target = $RefBef][1]/@BudgetaryEnvelop_Year"/></xsl:variable>
```

But this doesn't work. It doesn't execute the `value-of`. I tried to pass it like a string like this:

```
<xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:attribute name="select">//dbquery[@id='INLIJVING']//rows/row[<xsl:value-of select="$target"/>=<xsl:value-of select="$RefBef"/>][1]/@BudgetaryEnvelop_Year</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:value-of>
```

But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare an attribute specified by a variable, try something like:

```
row[ @*[ name() = $attrName ] = $RefBef ]
```

`@*` matches any attribute and the nested predicate filters the one with name `$attrName`. (So `$attrName` should not contain the `@` character.)

If you want to evaluate whole expressions dynamically, you'll need extension functions. See the question [Evaluate dynamic string as an XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591452/evaluate-dynamic-string-as-an-xpath-expression).

Answer (score 0):

Try an XPath similar to;

```
<xsl:value-of select="//dbquery[@id='INLIJVING']//rows/row/@*[local-name()=$target]/../@BudgetaryEnvelop_Year"/>
```

The `@*` returns all the attributes of `row` which we then filter by the name of the attribute. This leaves the XPath as selecting the attribute which is not what's desired so we use `..` to ascend back to `row` and decend into the desired `@BudgetaryEnvelop_Year` attribute.